# CreateView into Modal in the same page

Tags: django, django-models, modal-dialog, create-view

I have the following views:

```
class ArticleVideoCreate(CreateView):

    model = ArticleVideo
    fields = ['article', 'video', 'video_url']
```

and this url:

```
path('', CatalogListView.as_view()),
path('video/<int:article_id>/create', ArticleVideoCreate.as_view(), name='video-create')
```

I'm in the ListView page. and I have a button to add an article Video:

```
<a href="{% url 'video-create' article.sku %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" role="button" aria-pressed="true"><ion-icon name="videocam"></ion-icon></a>
```

In my articlevideo_form.html (for create the article video, is the modal):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that when I click the button to add an ArticleVideo, django redirects me to video//create with only the modal shown. Which is the best way to show the modal of the CreateView, in the same page, using Django? And clicking create and doing all in the same page?

Comment: may be you need to set the `success_url` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.success_url

Comment: I'm adding success_url = '' (because the url I want is CatalogListView) and Django keeps redirecting me

Comment: may be `success_url = '/'`?

Comment: use javascript/ajax to load the modal form from the create view and show it when clicking on the "add" button (remove the link to your create view from the "add" button) and to submit the form in the modal. if the submission is unsuccessful, redisplay the modal form with errors, if successful, show a success message.